# SQL Linked Servers Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

I have 2 Databases on 2 separate servers. There is 1 table that is a parent to these 2 databases which is located on a 3rd server. I linked the servers so I can query the parent table from the children databases.

However this is affecting the performance tremendously.

I am wondering if someone could help me on how to perform a query to a remote server without compromising on performance.

I have tried making a view to the parent table. I've also tried making a temp table variable to dump all the remote data to the local server.

Each of these is helping a drop but not enough.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Replicate the data from the parent to the children

Comment: I don't want to have all that maintainence. Storing the same info in 3 places? Is this good database design?

Comment: When you query through a linked server,it does try to apply a predicate on the remote server(if you have a predicate),but this is not guaranteed.so you will need to minimize data that is transferred from remote server..if you can post your query with some test data,some one can try applying predicate on remote server

Comment: minimizing the data wont help. The actual select from the remote server is nothing but then joining it and working with it is what takes long.

Comment: @Diane It is extremely common. While you are triple storing the data, it will solve the performance issue most likely (presuming everything is structured/indexed correctly). This issue is why data warehouses exist.

Comment: @Diane "Is this good database design?" Someone should have asked that question when it was decided to spread your collective data across three separate servers. You are paying the price for this decision, and the suggestion (replication) is the best answer if you must live with the original decision. The best db design is to keep all related data within a single database. Maybe it's time to reopen the barn doors and gather the animals.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I think I will just have to go with this and replicate the data. it's my best bet. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes boostin Linked server performance can be gained by using **openquery**

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER,'Select FirstName,LastName from 
DATABASENAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME')
```

This is not always performing better, but you can try it out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to have to hard code the linked server. In case it gets changed in the future...